# how to extract Infomix database informations from remote server using nagios?

Tags: oracle, centos, informix, nagios, nrpe

Concerning a project that I have to do in school, I have to develop a web application to supervise some remote machines (CentOS VM), its CPU, disk space and also the state of databases Oracle and Informix.

- can Nagios supervise an Oracle database?
- can Nagios supervise an Informix database?

I can't find an answer for the second question. Can someone give me a solution, an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

What does 'supervise' entail?

Assuming Nagios can connect to an Informix database as a suitably privileged user, it can be used to administer the database via the administration functional interface.  About the only thing that doesn't work straight-forwardly is bringing the server up from off-line to on-line status, but there is a technique for that, too.

You can find documentation for the `admin()` and `task()` functions at:

- [SQL Administration API — `admin()` and `task()` functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_1118.htm) and pages from there.

There are other related documents in the [Informix 12.10 Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm).